# C# Exception where Capacity is lower than Count

Tags: c#, list

I'm hitting an exception with a List in C# when I add an item in the list. I can't really see anything specific there.

`tempList.ForEach(tempDis => alloc.ListDistribution.Add(tempDis));`

When I hover `alloc.ListDistribution`, the debugger tells me there is 6 items in the list. If I try to expand those items, I have an exception that says:

> Source array was not long enough. Check srcIndex and length, and the
> array's lower bounds.    at System.Array.Copy(Array sourceArray, Int32
> sourceIndex, Array destinationArray, Int32 destinationIndex, Int32
> length, Boolean reliable)    at
> System.Collections.Generic.List`1.CopyTo(T[] array, Int32 arrayIndex)   at System.Collections.Generic.Mscorlib_CollectionDebugView`1.get_Items()

And I can see the Capacity of the list is 4, while the Count is 6. So the exception is triggered while the system is inceasing capacity.

While that makes no sense to me, the documentation of the mentions in the list of Exception that there is a scenario where:

> ArgumentOutOfRangeException Capacity is set to a value that is less than Count.

But in the remarks specifies this can't happen:
*Capacity is always greater than or equal to Count. If Count exceeds Capacity while adding elements, the capacity is increased by automatically reallocating the internal array before copying the old elements and adding the new elements.*

Any idea what could cause this exception to be triggered?

Comment: What is the type of `alloc.ListDistribution` (`List<T>` I guess) and are you accessing it from multiple threads? Please read [ask] and provide a [mre].

Comment: Is `alloc.ListDistribution.AddRange(tempList)` what you want to achive?

Comment: public List<DistributionQuantity> ListDistribution { get; set; }
nothing special, just a simple Class. 

I really have no idea how to reproduce this problem. It unfortunatly happens only very randomly. I do have multiple thread, they shouldn't access this data at the same time but for the purpose of the question, we should assume they do. I'm just wondering if anyone would be able to create a simple example to actually trigger this exception, which apparently cannot ever happen.

@sa.he Indeed I have split my initial code into smaller piece to reduce the potential cause of the problem.

Comment: @talrashha Does it only happen when viewing the list in the debugger?

Answer (score 2):

> I do have multiple thread, they shouldn't access this data at the same time but for the purpose of the question, we should assume they do

Then fix that, `List<T>` isn't thread-safe. If two threads add or remove items at the same time, its internal counters get messed up. Stuff then breaks when you access the list again, such as using the debugger to inspect its contents, but it can happen as well as when the next piece of code accesses it.

Synchronize your access to that list.

This exception isn't documented, because using it in multiple threads is not part of its supported usage.

Comment: I would go ahead and use one of the Thread-Safe Collection types provided by C#.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/

Answer (score 0):

You need to lock the list if you are going to add or remove objects in a multithread context. The only thread-safe operation on list is reading. Also, if you´re using foreach for iterating over a list, this shouldn't vary it's size.